# Ayuda con JCalendar

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, jcalendar

Tengo un problema en un proyecto , les comento:

Cree un método que captura un valor de JCalendar pero no se como usarlo para concatenarlo con una consulta sql o pasar ese valor a una variable para poder instanciarla desde la otra clases donde hago la consulta a la base de datos.
Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, no está permitido usar formato de imagen para el código. Deberías editar la respuesta incluyendo el código en formato de código así se puede copiar y pegar en el entorno de desarrollo

Comment: @JuanRom de hecho está totalmente permitido, aunque eso generalmente impedirá que obtenga buenas respuestas y es excluyente para personas que no pueden visualizar imágenes, ya sea por cuestiones físicas o de proxy corporativo.

Answer (score 1):

Mejor usa este formato de fecha: **yyyy-MM-dd**.
O sea quedaría:

```
public String obtenerFecha(){
  SimpleDateFormat formato =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String fecha =formato.format(jCalenadar1.getDate());
  return fecha;
}
```

Así funcionará pero no es una buena práctica de programación ya que estás creando un **nuevo** `SimpleDateFormat` por cada vez que ejecutes obtenerFecha(). Debes inicializar ese objeto `SimpleDateFormat` en el constructor de tu clase donde se encuentra el método `obtenerFecha()`. Así:

```
class TuClase{

  SimpleDateFormat formato;//declaración como atributo

  public TuClase{
    //...
    formato =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    //...
  }
}
```

Y `obtenerFecha()` te quedaría así:

```
public String obtenerFecha(){
  SimpleDateFormat formato =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String fecha =formato.format(jCalenadar1.getDate());
  return fecha;
}
```

Aunque no hace falta crear una variable, retornas directamente`formato.format(jCalenadar1.getDate());`.

Así:

```
public String obtenerFecha(){
  return formato.format(jCalenadar1.getDate());
}
```

Y por último en `getActividades()` le pasas la fecha a la consulta:

```
//donde pusiste:
"...and fecha=''");
//pones la fecha formateada, así:
"...and fecha="+"'"+obtenerFecha()+"'");//presta atención a las comillas
//fijate que cada comilla simple ' está encerrada entre comillas doble ""
```

Answer (score -1):

Hola para guardar una fecha de un `JCalendar` puedes usar esto.

```
            JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar();
            int año = calendar.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mes = calendar.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dia = calendar.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            String fecha = dia+"-"+mes+"-"+año;
            System.out.print(fecha);
```

Comment: supongo qeu el -1 que te dieron fue por usar ñ en tu código